# ¿Cómo le puedo agregar una scrollbar a este programa?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy creando un juego de preguntas, y esta es la segunda pantalla del juego, es muy larga, asi que **necesito crearle una scrollbar** para el usuario:

Os dejo mi código

```
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import * 
    #Dialogos emergentes
    from tkinter import messagebox
    #Barra de desplazamiento
    #Defino que hacen los botones de la primera pregunta 
    #Score
    #RESPUESTA A`introducir el código aquí`
    def accion_del_primer_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_uno = messagebox.showinfo("A. En el año 1939", "Muy bien, esta es la respuesta correcta :D")
    #RESPUESTA B
    def accion_del_segundo_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("B. En el año 1870", "Respondiste mal suerte para la proxima :C")
    #RESPUESTA C
    def accion_del_tercer_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("C. En el año 1900", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion A")
    
    #Defino que hacen los botones de la segunda pregunta
    #RESPUESTA A
    def accion_del_cuarto_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_uno = messagebox.showwarning("A. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 8m/s^2", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion C")
    #RESPUESTA B
    def accion_del_quinto_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("B. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 12m/s^2 ", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion C")
    #RESPUESTA C
    def accion_del_sexto_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showinfo("C. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 9,8m/s^2 ", "Muy bien, esta es la respuesta correcta :D")
    #Defino que hacen los botones de la tercera pregunta
    #RESPUESTA A
    def accion_del_septimo_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("A. El Autor de la Odisea fue Homero Simpson ", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion B")
    #RESPUESTA B
    def accion_del_octavo_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showinfo("B. El Autor de la Odisea fue Homero ", "Muy bien, esta es la respuesta correcta :D")
    #RESPUESTA C
    def accion_del_noveno_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("C. El Autor de la Odisea fue Dante Alighieri ", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion B")
    #Defino que hacen los botones de la cuarta pregunta
    #RESPUESTA A
    def accion_del_decimo_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("A. La capital de Polonia es Cracovia ", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion B")
    #RESPUESTA B
    def accion_del_onceavo_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showinfo("B. La capital de Polonia es Varsovia ", "Muy bien, esta es la respuesta correcta :D")
    #RESPUESTA C
    def accion_del_doceavo_boton():
        respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("C. La capital de Polonia es Breslavia", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion B")
    simon = tkinter.Tk()
    simon.geometry("500x500")
    simon.configure(background="dark turquoise")
    simon.title("Preguntamos¿?")
    #Eytiquetas
    e1=tkinter.Label(simon, text="¿Cual es tu nombre?:",bg="red", fg="White")
    e1.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
    #Que hacen los botones 
    #RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA 1
    primer_boton= tkinter.Button(text="A. En el año 1939", command= accion_del_primer_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    segundo_boton= tkinter.Button(text="B. En el año 1870",command= accion_del_segundo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    tercer_boton= tkinter.Button(text="C. En el año 1900",command= accion_del_tercer_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    #RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA 2
    cuarto_boton= tkinter.Button(text="A. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 8m/s^2",command= accion_del_cuarto_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    quinto_boton= tkinter.Button(text="B. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 12m/s^2",command= accion_del_quinto_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    sexto_boton= tkinter.Button(text="C. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 9,8m/s^2",command= accion_del_sexto_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    #RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA 3
    septimo_boton= tkinter.Button(text="A. El autor de la Odisea fue Homero Simpson",command= accion_del_septimo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    octavo_boton= tkinter.Button(text="B. El autor de la Odisea fue Homero",command= accion_del_octavo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    noveno_boton= tkinter.Button(text="C. El autor de la Odisea fue Dante Alighieri",command= accion_del_noveno_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    #RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA 4
    decimo_boton= tkinter.Button(text="A. La capital de Polonia es Cracovia ",command= accion_del_decimo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    onceavo_boton= tkinter.Button(text="B. La capital de Polonia es Varsovia ",command= accion_del_onceavo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    doceavo_boton= tkinter.Button(text="C. La capital de Polonia es Breslavia ",command= accion_del_doceavo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
    #se pone para que escriba
    nombre = tkinter.Entry(simon)
    nombre.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    #Etiquerta 2
    e2=tkinter.Label(simon, text="¿Cuando inicio la segunda guerra mundial?",bg="red", fg="white")
    e2.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
    #Coloco el boton
    primer_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    segundo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    tercer_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    #Etiquerta 3
    e3=tkinter.Label(simon, text="¿Cual es el valor de la gravedad ejercido sobre la tierar?",bg="red", fg="white")
    e3.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
    #Coloco el boton
    cuarto_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    quinto_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    sexto_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    #Etiqueta 4
    e3=tkinter.Label(simon, text="¿Quien escribió la Odisea?",bg="red", fg="white")
    e3.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
    #Coloco el boton
    septimo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    octavo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    noveno_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    #Etiqueta 5
    e4=tkinter.Label(simon, text="¿Cual es la capitla de Polonia?",bg="red", fg="white")
    e4.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
    #Coloco el boton
    decimo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    onceavo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    doceavo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    #Creo 
    simon.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo con su pregunta, es claro que es posible agregar una barra de desplazamiento en Python Tkinter en su programa, lo único que debe hacer es agregar a su código el widget Canvas y un Frame para organizar los widgets para poder usar la barra de desplazamiento, el cual se encarga de poder desplazar los widgets mediante una barra de desplazamiento lateral. Por lo cual su programa quedaría así:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import * 
#Dialogos emergentes
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

#Defino que hacen los botones de la primera pregunta 
#Score
#RESPUESTA A`introducir el código aquí`
def accion_del_primer_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_uno = messagebox.showinfo("A. En el año 1939", "Muy bien, esta es la respuesta correcta :D")
#RESPUESTA B
def accion_del_segundo_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("B. En el año 1870", "Respondiste mal suerte para la proxima :C")
#RESPUESTA C
def accion_del_tercer_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("C. En el año 1900", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion A")

#Defino que hacen los botones de la segunda pregunta
#RESPUESTA A
def accion_del_cuarto_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_uno = messagebox.showwarning("A. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 8m/s^2", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion C")
#RESPUESTA B
def accion_del_quinto_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("B. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 12m/s^2 ", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion C")
#RESPUESTA C
def accion_del_sexto_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showinfo("C. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 9,8m/s^2 ", "Muy bien, esta es la respuesta correcta :D")
#Defino que hacen los botones de la tercera pregunta
#RESPUESTA A
def accion_del_septimo_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("A. El Autor de la Odisea fue Homero Simpson ", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion B")
#RESPUESTA B
def accion_del_octavo_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showinfo("B. El Autor de la Odisea fue Homero ", "Muy bien, esta es la respuesta correcta :D")
#RESPUESTA C
def accion_del_noveno_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("C. El Autor de la Odisea fue Dante Alighieri ", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion B")
#Defino que hacen los botones de la cuarta pregunta
#RESPUESTA A
def accion_del_decimo_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("A. La capital de Polonia es Cracovia ", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion B")
#RESPUESTA B
def accion_del_onceavo_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showinfo("B. La capital de Polonia es Varsovia ", "Muy bien, esta es la respuesta correcta :D")
#RESPUESTA C
def accion_del_doceavo_boton():
    respuesta_pregunta_dos = messagebox.showwarning("C. La capital de Polonia es Breslavia", "Respondiste mal, suerte para la proxima :C - La respuesta correcta era la opcion B")
simon = tkinter.Tk()
simon.geometry("500x500")
simon.resizable(0,0) #Acá le deshabilite el maximizar de ventana. No es necesario que está habilitado.
simon.configure(background="dark turquoise")
simon.title("Preguntamos¿?")

AreaLabelFrame = LabelFrame(simon, bg='dark turquoise') #Área de la capa

CanvasWidget = Canvas(AreaLabelFrame, bg='dark turquoise', width=450) #El área donde se va a desplazar el widget
CanvasWidget.pack(side='left',fill='both')

ScrollbarWidget = ttk.Scrollbar(AreaLabelFrame, orient='vertical', command=CanvasWidget.yview) #Barra de desplazamiento
ScrollbarWidget.pack(side='right', fill='y')

CanvasWidget.config(yscrollcommand=ScrollbarWidget.set) 
CanvasWidget.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: CanvasWidget.config(scrollregion = CanvasWidget.bbox('all'))) #Configurara el evento de la barra de desplazamiento

def _on_mousewheel(event):
    CanvasWidget.yview_scroll(-1 * (event.delta // 120), "units") # Evento del mouse

CanvasWidget.bind('<MouseWheel>', _on_mousewheel) #Evento de movimiento de mouse.

FramaVentana = Frame(CanvasWidget, bg='dark turquoise') #Frame para mover los widgets.
CanvasWidget.create_window((0,0), window=FramaVentana) #Crea la capa para poder mover los widgets


AreaLabelFrame.pack(fill='y', expand='yes', padx=0, pady=0)
#Eytiquetas
e1=tkinter.Label(FramaVentana, text="¿Cual es tu nombre?:",bg="red", fg="White")
e1.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
#Que hacen los botones 
#RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA 1
primer_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana, text="A. En el año 1939", command= accion_del_primer_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
segundo_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana, text="B. En el año 1870",command= accion_del_segundo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
tercer_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana, text="C. En el año 1900",command= accion_del_tercer_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
#RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA 2
cuarto_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana, text="A. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 8m/s^2",command= accion_del_cuarto_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
quinto_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana, text="B. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 12m/s^2",command= accion_del_quinto_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
sexto_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana,text="C. El valor de la gravedad ejercida sobre la tierra es de 9,8m/s^2",command= accion_del_sexto_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
#RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA 3
septimo_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana,text="A. El autor de la Odisea fue Homero Simpson",command= accion_del_septimo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
octavo_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana,text="B. El autor de la Odisea fue Homero",command= accion_del_octavo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
noveno_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana,text="C. El autor de la Odisea fue Dante Alighieri",command= accion_del_noveno_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
#RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA 4
decimo_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana,text="A. La capital de Polonia es Cracovia ",command= accion_del_decimo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
onceavo_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana,text="B. La capital de Polonia es Varsovia ",command= accion_del_onceavo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
doceavo_boton= tkinter.Button(FramaVentana,text="C. La capital de Polonia es Breslavia ",command= accion_del_doceavo_boton, bg="white", fg="black")
#se pone para que escriba
nombre = tkinter.Entry(FramaVentana)
nombre.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
#Etiquerta 2
e2=tkinter.Label(FramaVentana, text="¿Cuando inicio la segunda guerra mundial?",bg="red", fg="white")
e2.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
#Coloco el boton
primer_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
segundo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
tercer_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
#Etiquerta 3
e3=tkinter.Label(FramaVentana, text="¿Cual es el valor de la gravedad ejercido sobre la tierar?",bg="red", fg="white")
e3.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
#Coloco el boton
cuarto_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
quinto_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
sexto_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
#Etiqueta 4
e3=tkinter.Label(FramaVentana, text="¿Quien escribió la Odisea?",bg="red", fg="white")
e3.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
#Coloco el boton
septimo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
octavo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
noveno_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
#Etiqueta 5
e4=tkinter.Label(FramaVentana, text="¿Cual es la capitla de Polonia?",bg="red", fg="white")
e4.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tkinter.X)
#Coloco el boton
decimo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
onceavo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
doceavo_boton.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
#Creo 
simon.mainloop()
```